# Leaflet center Marker AND Popup on Map viewport

Tags: leaflet, javascript, web-mapping, popup

I want center my marker on popup open.. and centering map not in marker latlng, but on center of marker and popup! The problem is that popup has dinamic content(loaded on click).

The map size is full display size in a mobile device! I'm just used autoPanPadding option in popup but not sufficient

Refer to follow picture:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was also asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538473/leaflet-center-popup-and-marker-to-the-map), and answered by Dan Mandle.

```
map.on('popupopen', function(e) {
    // find the pixel location on the map where the popup anchor is
    var px = map.project(e.popup._latlng);
   // find the height of the popup container, divide by 2 to centre, subtract from the Y axis of marker location
    px.y -= e.popup._container.clientHeight/2;
    // pan to new center
    map.panTo(map.unproject(px),{animate: true});
});
```

Comment: Could you explain exactly what your code does with comments and accept it as a solution?

Comment: There are 3 lines of code is self explanatory

Comment: @StefanoCudini It is always a good gesture to credit the [actual author](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23960984) for exactly the same question you have asked [elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22538473).

Comment: @GISKid The actual answer has **explanatory** comments.

Comment: @thelastray good catch

Comment: The solution is copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538473/leaflet-center-popup-and-marker-to-the-map/23960984#23960984. I have tried to update the answer, but Stefano reverted my update.